# Protobuf-Net ProtoMember "IsRequired" attribute usage

Tags: protobuf-net

What is the usage for the Protobuf-Net ProtoMember "IsRequired" attribute?

What effect will it have if I add a new property (member) to an already serialized class in a file. If I use "IsRequired=true" will it just accept it without loading a value (since it's not there) or should I set the value to false? And if I set it to false, will the value be serialized properly?

Comment: I've just returned from a few days away. I will look at this later

Comment: **See Also**: [Github protobuf-net - Issues #120](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/issues/120)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to *[Issue 262: ProtoMembers with IsRequired=true aren't really required](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/issues/detail?id=262)*:

> Currently, IsRequired primarily impacts **serialization**, forcing it to ignore some default rules.

When IsRequired is false (the default), default values are not serialized, e.g. an integer value of 0 would not be serialized, a value of 1 would.

When IsRequired is true, all values, including default values, are serialized.

Deserialization using [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) currently seems unaffected by the the value of the IsRequired attribute. However if you are using a different implementation of [Google Protocol Buffers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers) for deserialization you may see different behavior.

If you add a new property to an existing class, and deserialize a serialized file written before the property was added, the new property will simply not be set.